# Use Dirac's theorem to show that if $G+uv$ is hamiltonian then $G$ is hamiltonian.

Tags: graph-theory

Question:
Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and $u,v$ two non-adjacent vertices such that $deg(u) + deg(v) \geq n$. 
Use Dirac's theorem to show that if $G+uv$ (for an edge $uv$) is hamiltonian then $G$ is hamiltonian.

My attempt:
Suppose $G+uv$ is hamiltonian. For any vertices $k \in V(G+uv), k \neq u,v$, we have $deg_{G}(k)=deg_{G+uv}(k) \geq \frac {n}{2}$.

Now consider the vertice $u$.

Then $deg_{G}(u) = deg_{G+uv}(u) -1 \geq \frac {n}{2} -1$. And this is where I am stuck seeing as this is clearly not the desired result that $deg_{G}(u) \geq \frac {n} {2}$.

Comment: The converse of Dirac's theorem is false: you *can't* derive $\deg_{G+uv}(k) \ge \frac n2$ from the fact that $G+uv$ is Hamiltonian. More generally, I'm pretty sure this result (the Bondy-Chvátal theorem) can't be proved from Dirac's theorem - but its proof is very similar to the inductive step in the proof of Dirac's theorem.

Comment: @MishaLavrov if G+uv is hamiltonian every vertex in G+uv has degree greater than or equal to n/2 by dirac's theorem. Is this statement not true?

Comment: That statement is false, yes. (For example, a cycle graph on $n$ vertices is Hamiltonian, yet every vertex has degree $2$, which is $< \frac n2$ for $n \ge 5$.) Dirac's theorem says the opposite: if $\deg v \ge \frac n2$ for all $v$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

Comment: @MishaLavrov ok yes I see.